# Limit c:forEach to a maximum when using an c:if condition in its body

Tags: jstl

I've got a problem with if condition. I'm getting data from DB and everything is viewed on 2 website tables. Tables on website should be limited to 3 rows only. In DB there is a column named 'screen'. 'screen' can be 'first', 'second' or 'both'. 'first' is a first table, 'second' is a second table, 'both' means both tables. For example if I add data as 'first' screen it should be viewed in first table, if I add data as 'both' it should be viewed in both tables etc. I limited it to 3 rows so the problem is if I add 3 'first' screens and 1 'both' screen I see 3 rows on first table but there isn't any row at second screen. That code is for first table:

```
<c:forEach items="${foo}" var="c" varStatus="status">
      <c:if test="${status.count <= 3 && c.screen.equals('both') || status.count <= 3 && c.screen.equals('first')}">

            <tr><td>something_bla_bla</td></tr>

      </c:if>
 </c:forEach>
```

Code for second table is almost same - diffrence is only c.screen.equals('second')
Adding 3 'first' shows 3 rows - that's OK,
Adding 3 'both' shows 3 rows - that's OK,
But if I add 3 'first' and 1 'both' that 'both' record should be viewed in second table and it isn't because of that 3 limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of counting how many rows you have outputted. For example:

```
<c:set var="count" value="0"/>
<c:forTokens items="first,second,second,both,first,both,second"
             delims=","
             var="item">
  <c:if test="${count lt 3 and 'both,first'.contains(item)}">
    <c:out value="${item}"/>
    <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forTokens>

<br/>

<c:set var="count" value="0"/>
<c:forTokens items="first,second,second,both,first,both,second"
             delims=","
             var="item">
  <c:if test="${count lt 3 and 'both,second'.contains(item)}">
    <c:out value="${item}"/>
    <c:set var="count" value="${count + 1}"/>
  </c:if>
</c:forTokens>
```

This will output (ignoring whitespace):

```
first both first<br/>
second second both
```

Please note that I'm using `'both,first'.contains(item)` which has the same effect as `(item eq 'both' or item eq 'first')`, but is shorter (especially if you would have move strings to check).